# FFMpeg generates still video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, thumbnails, ffprobe

I'm doing a simple test of ffmpeg. I'd like to use it for thumbnail generation / video grabbing for a website I'm developing. I'm currently using VLC to grab a single frame and then generate a thumbnail, but it's rather slow and a bit cumbersome.

The problem is that the video I'm using (from my own pc) is generated by security camera software and it has an odd video format. When I open it (.bvr) in VLC, it plays very, very fast. A 10 second video goes by in about 2.5 seconds. Additionally, using a simple convert with ffmpeg "ffmpeg -i test.bvr output.avi" generates a proper-length video (10 seconds), but the video frame never changes. (It's a still image)

Test file and test output file:

- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95418255/test.bvr
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95418255/output.avi

I think this is primarily caused by the fact that the IP cameras may only generate 5-7 fps but the security software doesn't know better and writes it as if it should be 24/30 fps.

> FFMpeg Reports: [m4v @ 00000000002cec60] Estimating duration from
>   bitrate, this may be inaccurate Input #0, m4v, from 'test.bvr':
>   Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4
>   (Simple Profile), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 5 tbr, 1200k
>   tbn, 5 tbc Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi': Metadata: ISFT
>   : Lavf54.25.104 Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46),
>   yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 5 tbn, 5 tbc
>   Stream mapping:
>
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> mpeg4) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   frame=   50 fps=0.0 q=2.0 Lsize=     244kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=
>   199.7kbits/s video:237kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.877066%**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps it is unable to determine the framerate but understands how to decode the stream. Have you tried forcing a constant framerate of 6 fps?

Comment: The problem is that although in *this* case it's my own video, it will generally be customers uploading their own stuff. I have no idea what the framerate *should* be.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question. But here is my input anyways. The content produced is mpeg4 elementary stream. So there is no way this will be played at correct frame rate by vlc.

Secondly your video is a static frame with one illumination change only and with the time code increasing below at bottom right from 21s to 32s. So are you saying that your output video does not the time code changing at the bottom right?

EDIT: vlc is not able to play it for me too. However ffplay is able to play it fine at my end and also you can use ffmpeg to grab the thumbnail wherever you want.

EDIT: This works with vlc as well:

ffmpeg -i input.dvr -vcodec mpeg4 output.avi

This plays in vlc as well. One thing is you should give the target bitrate and resolution as well.

Comment: When I open the 'output.avi' file the timer stays constant and the video never changes. I have the latest version of VLC. The reason this is all important is that I must programatically grab a frame about halfway through to generate a thumbnail, but the user's video may have all sorts of issues like this. I was asking these questions before trying to dive into the deeper stuff (grabbing total # of frames, etc.)

Comment: Yes, vlc is not able to play it. However ffplay is able to play it fine at my end and also you can use ffmpeg to grab the thumbnail wherever you want.

Comment: @JasonMuchow, do you need an avi only? If you replace with avi with mp4 it works fine in vlc as well. I could check what is wrong with the avi though sometime tomorrow

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I've tried converting another video, as well as using your suggestion of vcodec mpeg4, but VLC simply remains on a single frame. I should note that ffmpeg is the windows compiled version... none-the-less, all I really want, in the end, is to get the total number of frames then divide by two and grab it for a thumbnail. (50% way through video)

Comment: @JasonMuchow, my ffplay plays your generated video fine. Vlc shows the first frame. If I convert it to a mp4 also it plays fine in both vlc and ffplay. So I am not sure what issue you are facing.  Try the following:   ffprobe inputfile   This should print the duration of the file. You can simply parse this output using a simple script and get the duration/2.    Next try this command on the input directly.  You can also do it on the output of your ffmpeg command. It works both ways.    ffmpeg -i <file> -vframes 1 -ss <duration/2>  -f image2 -s widthxheight out.jpg.